# Pythonのreturn文 (戻り値) について教えてください

Tags: python, windows-10

## Pythonのreturn文の働きを詳しく納得がいくように知りたい。

●次の例文の**return self.num**と**return self.gas**について

返り値のreturnはそもそもどういう時に使うのですか？どういう働きをして、プログラムの処理の流れはどういう風になっているのでしょうか？
僕の見解では「関数の呼び出し元に関数本体から情報を流す」と、そのまま覚えています。

このプログラムの**return**はプログラムのどこに進むかを特に教えてください。

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, num, gas):
        self.num = num
        self.gas = gas

    def getNumber(self):
        return self.num

    def getGas(self):
        return self.gas

cr1 = Car(1234, 25.5)
n1 = cr1.getNumber()
g1 = cr1.getGas()

cr2 = Car(2345, 30.5)
n2 = cr2.getNumber()
g2 = cr2.getGas()

print("ナンバーは", n1, "ガソリンの量は", g1, "です。")
print("ナンバーは", n2, "ガソリンの量は", g2, "です。")
```

**実行結果**
ナンバーは1234 ガソリンの量は25.5です。
ナンバーは2345 ガソリンの量は30.5です。

Comment: [Visualize Python, Java, JavaScript, C, C++, Ruby code execution](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) に質問欄のコードをコピーして "Visualize Execution" をクリックすると、別画面に移動します。そこで、"Next>" ボタンをクリックするとコードをステップ実行してインスタンスの状態などが表示されます。参考にしてみて下さい。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**【質問に対する直接の回答】**

> 返り値のreturnはそもそもどういう時に使うのですか？

呼び出し側がメソッドに対して処理を依頼し、処理の結果を呼び出し側が受け取りたいときに使います。

> どういう働きをして、プログラムの処理の流れはどういう風になっているのでしょうか？

後述の【プログラムの処理の流れ】を参照してください。
メソッドを呼び出した側にreturnで指定した値が返ります。
具体例で説明すると
(5)で呼び出したメソッド`getNumber`のreturnで返す値(self.num)が、呼び出し側の変数n1に代入されます。

**【プログラムの処理の流れ】**

(数値)は文の実行順序です。

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, num, gas):
        (2)(12)self.num = num
        (3)(13)self.gas = gas

    def getNumber(self):
        (6)(16)return self.num

    def getGas(self):
        (9)(19)return self.gas

(4)cr1 = (1)Car(1234, 25.5)
(7)n1 = (5)cr1.getNumber()
(10)g1 = (8)cr1.getGas()

(14)cr2 = (11)Car(2345, 30.5)
(17)n2 = (15)cr2.getNumber()
(20)g2 = (18)cr2.getGas()

(21)print("ナンバーは", n1, "ガソリンの量は", g1, "です。")
(22)print("ナンバーは", n2, "ガソリンの量は", g2, "です。")
```